# Adding annotations to eps file

Tags: vector-graphics, eps, annotations

How do I add some text into an existing eps file? I want an output eps file having the same quality as the input eps file, with the stipulation that the text etc. added should also be scalable (vector).

These sort of things are definitely possible with non-vector images, but I am not aware of any analogy for vector formats.

Comment: Removed software rec component of question.

Comment: @Karan - That would be fine as long as the answer includes which software accomplishes that :P Thanks :)

Comment: Well any solution would have to, right? You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could import the `.eps` file, draw on it with a text drawing library then re-export it. That can be done in GNU Octave (using `annotate()` function), python and a few others. If you'd rather not write code, you should be import your `.eps` file into [www.geogebra.org](http://www.geogebra.org), and add an annotation there and then re-export.